# How can one copy account data from one org to another without errors? Is it possible to do so without mapping all fields?

Tags: account, data, sales-cloud, upsert, upload

How can this upload be done without mapping all the fields from source instance? Is it possible to do so without any errors?

Answer (score 2):

Speaking generally, you can't. Mapping fields is required.

Computers aren't magic (and are rather dumb, once you peek behind the veil).

If there is *any* difference between your two orgs

- number of fields
- the API names of the fields
- the data type of the field
- validation rules on the SObject
- flows/triggers on the SObject

Then someone, somewhere, at some point in time is going to need to put in work to deal with those differences. That's going to be a massive amount of work unless you are really lucky and/or really prepared.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late with my answer, but the one answer provided appears to me a bit suboptimal. There are of course ways to migrate SObjects (e.g. Accounts) from one org to another without mapping fields - provided the fields on source and target org are (api) named the same. As an example take the [SFDX Data Move Utility](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SFDX-Data-Move-Utility):

1. Make sure you have the `sfdx` CLI (yes, the older CLI tool and not `sf`!) installed on your box.
2. Install SFDMU according to recommendations on the given Github start page.
3. Create a file export.json in the same directory that you will use to execute `sfdx`. The Github page has an example for an Account migration. Providing the list of fields that you want to migrate is enough.
4. Execute

```
sfdx sfdmu:run --sourceusername [your user name on the source org] --targetusername [your user name on the target org]
```

I'm sure Derek F is aware of such options, so regard this as a supplement...